# Rudin chapter 1 exercise 16, Proof verification(?)

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to solve the following problem in Rudin, Principles of Mathematical Analysis :

Suppose 
$ k≥3$,$~~$ $ x,y∈ℝ^k,~~|x−y|=d>0~~~x,y∈R^k,|x−y|=d>0, and$ $ r>0 $

Prove:

If $2r>d,$ there are infinitely many $z$ such that:

$\textbf{|z−x|=|z−y|=r}$

If we apply geometric intuition then we see there are infinitely many vectors $w$ such that $w.(x-y) = 0$. For example, in case of $k=3$, the intersection of the two spheres, $\textbf{|z-x| = |z-y|}$, is a circle, and in this case the vectors w are the points on this circle.

And, we have $\textbf{z.(x-y)} = 1/2(|x|^2 - |y|^2)$

Therefore, $z= c+w$, where $c = 1/2(\textbf{x+y})$, is a solution to the above equation.

Is this enough, what else do i need to show?

And, moreover is there any way to show algebraically that there are infinitely many such w.

Comment: I believe you want $c=(x+y)/2$, so that $x-c=c-y=(x-y)/2$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'll edit it. But apart from that do you think the solution is correct.